# Python app Not loading data from file correctly

Tags: python

I have a python IRC Bot that allows a user to play games in the irc chat and define terms and nicknames etc.

What my issue is is that whenever someone defines a term or a nickname it saves until the program reboots (when I update it) and when it joins back it's lost everything and prints an error into the console saying that it failed to load the data. With the help of the people who posted with the version before this I managed to figure out it was a json issue with the text file I was loading from.

This is the code to load:

```
nicks = dict() 
f = open("nicks.txt", "r") # read-only
print("[INFO]LOADING NICKS...")
time.sleep(1)
for line in f.readlines():
  try:
    if len(line.strip())>0:
      user, nick= json.loads(line.strip())
      nicks[user] = json.dumps(nick)
  except:
    print("[ERROR]Cant load nick: %s" % line)
f.close()
```

This is the code that saves the nickname

```
  elif (used_prefix and cmd == "nick"): ##making sure the prefix was used for the function
      try:
          if args:
              nick = args
              user=user.name
              user ,nick = user.lower(),nick.lower()##Lowers the characters in user nickname
              nicks[user] = json.dumps(nick)
              file = open("nicks.txt", 'a')
              file.write(""+nick+ '\n')
              file.close()

              room.message(user +", I'll now call you "+nick)
      except:
          room.message("failed -_-")
```

Fixed Code:

```
print("[SAVE] SAVING NICKS...")
          f = open("Nicks.txt", "w")
          for user in nicks:
              nick = json.loads(nicks[user])
              f.write(json.dumps([user, nick])+"\n")
          f.close()
```

I just don't understand what to do with it. I'm completely new to python coding.

EDIT: I fixed the issue I was having. I updated the question with the fixed code as well as the broken code. Hopefully it helps other users

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You have a bare except.  Get rid of the try and the except and error print and you'll see the actual error.

Comment: Will do, I'll update the post with the actual result.
edit: Turns out that they are both a JSON Error. Thanks for the help Patrick. Now I just have to get it saving in Json instead of as plain text.

Comment: What should this `nicks[user] = json.dumps(nick)` line do? Also this - `except: ...` is bad. It's ok (not really, but if you're new to python you can probably ignore it for now) to have this in your code after it's complete and works. That's not the case here so remove/comment out both the `try:` (only the try not the whole block of code) and remove/comment out the whole except block - then you should see exactly where and what error it gives you.

Comment: David It's a JSON parse error. I already diagnosed that

Answer (score 1):

You're using json to load the file but not for saving it. Also you're not loading it right (it's way too complicated your way).

Use something like this for saving:

```
with open('your_file.json', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     json.dump(your_data, f)
```

And something like this for loading:

```
with open('your_file.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     loaded_data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Just tried your method there. Works fine for loading but Saving fails. With a bit of tweaking it should be fine though. Thanks for the help David.

Comment: @LightningMods Just tested it and works fine for me. What error do you get?

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment error. Not sure if it's just my shoddy coding with python. What i'm doing is saving it to a text file which reads on running the program and prints to the console. When a user defines a nickname it will save it in the text file and allow the nickname to be there until the user changes it. In the code I have in he original post it saved it and worked until the program rebooted which would then throw the error that the usernames could not be loaded due to them not being Json.

Comment: @LightningMods I think you're doing something like `some_string[0] = "text"`. You can ask another question with the code or update this one.